# Remove every second comma from string (python)

Tags: python, regex

I would like to remove every second occurence of a comma in my string but starting from the second comma.
My string: "30, 20, 40, 50"
and I would like my result to be: "30 20, 40 50"
So far I have been using regular expressions to try and achieve this by the following reg sub: `myString = re.sub('(,[^,])*,', r'\1', myString)` but this results in: "30, 20 40, 50".
I hope someone can help me out here.

Comment: I got "30 20 40 50" for this expression and not "30, 20 40, 50" on my machine.

Comment: Please stop editing the thread with mistakes. Leave it as is and move on, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those that responded.
My own solution meanwhile ended up being:
`myString = re.sub(',([^,]*[,]*)', r'\1', myString)`

Answer (score 5):

You can group the non-comma characters and the optional following comma for preservation instead:

```
myString = re.sub(',([^,]*,?)', r'\1', myString)
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/EminentWholeOctagons

Comment: Will mark your response as the solution as it managed to do the same. Thanks.